# Resetting/Stopping session PHP

Tags: php, session

I've started to make a BlackJack game using as much PHP as possible and now i've got this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// cards on pile
if(!isset($_SESSION["pile"])) $_SESSION["pile"] = array(
  1           =>  1,
  2           =>  2,
  3           =>  3,
  4           =>  4,
  5           =>  5,
  6           =>  6,
  7           =>  7,
  8           =>  8,
  9           =>  9,
  10          =>  10,
  'Jack'      =>  10,
  'Queen'     =>  10,
  'King'      =>  10,
  'Ace'       =>  11);

// cards in hand
if(!isset($_SESSION["hand"])) $_SESSION["hand"] = array();

// draw a card from the pile into the hand
function draw_card() {
  $card = array_rand($_SESSION["pile"]);
  $_SESSION["hand"][$card] = $_SESSION["pile"][$card];
  unset($_SESSION["pile"][$card]);
}

function list_hand() {
  foreach($_SESSION["hand"] as $card=>$points) {
    echo 'Card: ' . $card . '<br>';
    echo 'Points: ' . $points . '<br><br>';
  }
}

// detect which form was triggered
function FORM($value) {
  return isset($_POST["form"]) && $_POST["form"]==$value;
}

// handle the draw form
if(FORM("draw")){
draw_card();
list_hand();
}
?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="draw">
  <input type="submit" value="Draw a card">
</form>
```

Sorry for dropping a bomb of code on you guys.

The problem with this is that when this page opens it will start the session. And give me standard 1 card, each time i refresh. (it will add up) I know this is the point of a session in the first place, but not the point of my page. I need the session to end when the page refreshes or if the page closes. I've had no luck searching the internet. Tried things as onUnload and many other things.

Secondly Since it keeps adding cards untill all 14 are drawn. It will add one last `Card: 
Points:` and at the top say `Notice: Undefined index`.

I had my first contact with sessions using this very script. So i'm a bit of a loss where the end/reset my session and if i can bind this to a button.

So to sum my problems up:

Session needs to reset/stop upon refreshing or closing page.

It shouldn't draw 1 standard card upon opening the page. (I'd rather have 0 and a button that will add 2, maybe a Start button or something)

The session needs to automatically stop whenever the last card is drawn out of my array. (This isn't that important since in no case ever is it possible that one player in blackjack can hold all cards)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need to reset the session on each page load, why use a session at all?

Comment: I agree with @ToBe you should be using a different mechanism for storing data if you don't need the data across pages. Otherwise, just destroy the session at the end of the file.

Comment: you would be better off doing this (black jack game) in JS honestly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to clean your session variables every time the user loads the page.

If this is your problem, you only need to use [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/session_destroy) at the beginning of the page.

You can unset all your session variables with the unset method too.